# I want my Random Forest to recognize a simple non-linear model

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, random-forest, nonlinearity

I have generated probabilities from 0 to 1 based on a non-linear function of my 4 covariates:

$X_1 + X_2^2 + X_3 + X_4$

I am hoping to use an off the shelf machine learning method to estimate the probabilities to show how machine learning may be superior to logistic regression in this non-linear situation. I don't want to spend a ton of time tuning the model, because I'm only trying to show that the ML method offers improvement, and naturally picks up on the non-linear term without the user explicitly specifying.

Any advice on how I may setup a random forest in R (or perhaps a method that would recognize this non-linearity better)? I am only feeding the ML model $\mathbf{X}=X_1, X_2, X_3,$ and $X_4$.

The quick off the shelf method has not been superior to logistic regression:

```
  rf = randomForest(x=X, y=label, data=df, sampsize=0.8*nrow(X), ntree=500)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that your problem lies in how you're generating your data or comparing the two models, but we can't know unless you share the full program.

Comment: Are you feeding $X_2^2$ to logistic regression? If so, no other model will beat it, it's the true model after all

Comment: Also, logistic regression can also be used in machine learning :)

Comment: Another important note is how you're generating $X$. For instance, if $X_2$ only ranges over $[10, 12]$, then the difference between $X_2^2$ and the best linear approximation is going to be small. Or if $X_1$ varies much wider than $X_2$, the $X_2$ effect is going to be small. Or if `nrow(X)` is quite small, the nearly-linear function you're using will mean LR is actually a better prior than the RF, even though the RF will do better as $\texttt{nrow}(X) \to \infty$. Or a host of other possible reasons....

Comment: If you want logistic regression to do badly, make sure you generate probabilities from a function of $X$ that cannot be well approximated by $\frac{1}{1 + \exp(-X\beta)}$. You haven't told us how exactly you did but, but what you've said so far is consistent with the logit model being a good approximation to the truth ...

Comment: Clarification on how I generate the probabilities: The probabilities are generated as a function of $\frac{1}{1+exp(-\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\beta})}$, where $\mathbf{X}$ includes $X_2^2$ as opposed to just $X_2$. When I estimate the logistic regression and run the RF, I am using $X_2$ as if the researcher is unaware of the quadratic effect on the outcome. I want to show that RF might do a good job of identifying that quadratic component. Obviously logistic regression isn't going to do a good job when I don't give it $X_2^2$.

Comment: Logit will do a great job for your setting compared to pretty much all standard models. I mean, the logit model is exactly right except one term is quadratic. All other models have to actually learn that the other stuff is linear at the log odds scale. Logit is here closer to the truth than in most real settings! If you want to stick with this data generating process, I suggest you make $\beta_2$ large relative to the others and $X_2$ symmetric around 0. The former makes $X_2$ important for the real probabilities, the latter makes the linear approximation to the quadratic bad.

Comment: I dug back into my code and realized I made a mistake in my running my random forest. Thanks to all that were skeptical about my data generating process. Random forest and XGBoost perform better than logistic regression when I just feed the models the first-order terms, which makes perfect sense.